# xcopy error in creating a task to copy directories and files

Tags: sbt

I want to create an `sbt` task to copy directories and files using `xcopy` in Windows10. I am getting following error. What is the mistake?

```
val copyCommonFilesInPublicKey = taskKey[Int]("Copies files in ../common/css and ../common/javascripts in public/stylesheet/common and public/javascripts/common")

copyCommonFilesInPublicKey := {
    val copyCSS = Process(s"xcopy  /i ../common/css public/stylesheets/common").!< //I had to use / instead of \ in path
    println(s"copy CSS returned ${copyCSS}")
    val copyJS = Process(s"xcopy  /i ../common/javascripts public/javascripts/common").!<
    println(s"copy JS returned ${copyJS}")
    copyJS
}
```

Error

```
Invalid number of parameters
copy CSS returned 4
Invalid number of parameters
copy JS returned 4
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 18-Jan-2018 15:03:32
```

The commands run fine on `cmd`. I suspect it could be the issue with `/i` as I couldn't run the command by giving the path using `\`. I tried changing `/i` to `\\i` but I got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split the arguments:

```
    val copyCommonFilesInPublicKey = taskKey[Int]("Copies files in ../common/css and ../common/javascripts in public/stylesheet/common and public/javascripts/common")

copyCommonFilesInPublicKey := {
    val copyCSS = Process(Seq("xcopy", "/i", "..\\common\\css", "public\\stylesheets\\common")).!<
    println(s"copy CSS returned ${copyCSS}")
    val copyJS = Process(Seq("xcopy", "/i", "..\\common\\javascripts", "public\\javascripts\\common")).!<
    println(s"copy JS returned ${copyJS}")
    copyJS
}
```

Comment: This worked `Process(Seq("xcopy", "/i", "..\\common\\css", "public\\stylesheets\\common")).!< `

Comment: I see, thanks @ManuChadha I've incorporated your fixes in the answer